# Date comparison getting error

Tags: javascript, jquery

we stuck date comparison, we tried the below code. EndDate value is related to jan 21, 2016 but in alert showing showing `Fri Sep 01 2017 10:10:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`, could you please share me your ideas

```
var endDateVal = "21/01/2016 10:10:10".replace(/-/gi, "/");
alert(new Date(endDateVal));
if (new Date(endDateVal) > new Date()) {
    alert("Last end date should be minor than today");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k166m6m6/709/)

Comment: Month should come before day in the date; eg. `"01/21/2016 10:10:10"`.

Comment: your format need to correct from `"21/01/2016 10:10:10"` to `"2016-01-21 10:10:10"`

Comment: im getting end date dynamically, is there any way change  end date to mm/dd/yyyy insted on dd/mm/yyyy using javascript, if any please suggest me

Answer (score 2):

The date is formatted incorrectly. The date needs to be an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) or [IETF-compliant RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) formatted date, like:

```
2016-01-21T10:10:10+05:30
```

To format the date you have you could do some thing like:

```
var dateVars = "21/01/2016 10:10:10".match(/\d+/g);
var reformattedDate = dateVars[2] + '-' + dateVars[1] + '-' + dateVars[0] + 'T' + dateVars[3] + ':' + dateVars[4] + ':' + dateVars[5] + '+05:30';
new Date(reformattedDate);
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to, other formats work as well - but all bets are off whether they work consistently across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First, `new Date("21/01/2016 10:10:10")` returns `Invalid Date`. Default format for Date is `mm/dd/yyyy` and not `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Second, when comparing dates, you should use `date.getTime()` instead.

Following is a sample code.

```js
var endDateVal = "02/21/2016 10:10:10";
var d1 = new Date(endDateVal)
var d2 = new Date();

console.log(d1, d2)
if (+d1 > +d2) {
  alert("Last end date should be minor than today");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap your day/month around to `01/21/2016 10:10:10`.

Also, Im not sure why you are using `.replace(/-/gi, "/");` as this is replacing a `-` with `/` where your date does not have any `-`.